# How many inverse numbers equal only odd numbers under 1 billion

Tags: python, math

I am trying to write a script that will allow me to come up with the value below.

> When certain integers greater than zero are summed with their transposed value `[x + transpose(x)]` the result is a number consisting of only odd digits.
>   For example:
>
> ```
> 54 + 45 = 99 
> 605 + 506 = 1111
> ```
>
> We will call these numbers flip-flops; so 45, 54, 506, and 605 are flip-flops. Zeroes are not acceptable leading digits in either `x` or `tran‍‍spose(x)‍‍‍‍`.
>   How many flip-flop numbers are there below one billion `(10^9)`?

I'm thinking of it this way in pseudo-code:

```
IF [x+TRANSPOSE(x)] = ODD NUMBERS ONLY
THEN FLIPFLOP = TRUE

HOW MANY FLIPFLOPS <1,000,000,000
```

I'm struggling with the syntax however. Can anyone help? I'm trying to do this in Python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it takes an odd plus an even number to make an odd number, you need an odd and an even number to make a flipflop. This limits the number of candidates you need to test to find all flipflops < 10**9.

Furthermore, since the flipflop pairs are composed of an odd and even number, one of the numbers must begin with an odd number and the other must begin with an even number.

Therefore, the even number in a flipflop must be of the form

```
[odd_digits] + [zero_to_nine]*(ndigits-2) + [even_digits]
```

In other words, it begins with an odd digit, ends with an even digit, and can be any digit in the middle.

The final `even_digit` can not be zero since the odd flipflop can not begin with zero.

You only need to generate all the candidate even numbers of the above form, since when you reverse the digits you get the candidate odd numbers. To do more than this would be to count the same flipflops twice.

---

A further optimization for speed is to use integers only. No strings. Generally, converting between ints and strings takes more time than arithmetic computations.

---

```
import itertools as IT
zero_to_nine = range(10)
even_digits = [2, 4, 6, 8]
odd_digits = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
flipflops = 0
for ndigits in range(2, 10):
    for digits in IT.product(*(
            [odd_digits] + [zero_to_nine]*(ndigits-2) + [even_digits])):
        reversed_digits = digits[::-1]
        carry = 0
        # print('testing {!r}'.format(digits))
        for a, z in zip(digits, reversed_digits):
            total = a+z+carry
            # print('total: {}'.format(total))
            if total % 2 == 0:
                break
            else:
                carry = total//10
        else:
            # print('{!r} + {!r}'.format(digits, reversed_digits))
            flipflops += 1
print(flipflops)
```

yields

```
304360
```

in about 6 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not patient enough to wait for 1 billion, so here is an example up to 1000.

```
odds = set('13579')
for num in range(1,1000):
    if not num % 10:
        continue
    inverse = int(str(num)[::-1])
    s = str(num + inverse)
    if all(i in odds for i in s):
        print('Num: {}, Inverse: {}, Flip: {}'.format(num, inverse, s))
```

Output

```
Num: 12, Inverse: 21, Flip: 33
Num: 14, Inverse: 41, Flip: 55
Num: 16, Inverse: 61, Flip: 77
Num: 18, Inverse: 81, Flip: 99
Num: 21, Inverse: 12, Flip: 33
....
Num: 938, Inverse: 839, Flip: 1777
Num: 942, Inverse: 249, Flip: 1191
Num: 944, Inverse: 449, Flip: 1393
Num: 946, Inverse: 649, Flip: 1595
Num: 948, Inverse: 849, Flip: 1797
```

**Edit**
If you just want the count, and don't care what values satisfy the criteria

```
total = 0
odds = set('13579')
for num in range(1,1000):
    if not num % 10:
        continue
    inverse = int(str(num)[::-1])
    s = str(num + inverse)
    if all(i in odds for i in s):
        total += 1
print(total)
```

Comment: Please forgive me, I'm a total noob - it's just saying invalid syntax. I'm using Python 2.7.8

Comment: I love you! That's what it was. Is there way to get just a sum of the total numbers vs listing them all?

Comment: When I try to run it up to 1,000,000,000 it gives me a memory error

Comment: "Zeroes are not acceptable leading digits in either `x` or `tran‍‍spose(x)‍‍‍‍`."

Comment: Ok, that's perfect! Now I just can't get the total for the range up to 1 bil. Still giving me a memory error

Comment: So the syntax would be for num in xrange(1,1000000000)?

Comment: A couple of questions since I'm such an amateur. Why the line "if not num % 10: continue?

Comment: @Jonathan That is a(n unclear) way for me to check if the number ends in a `0`. If it ends in a zero like 20 or 530, it will be divisible by 10, so when I do the mod operation (% 10) it will return a remainder of 0. So if there is a non-zero remainder, it will evaluate to True, and not skip that number. If it ends in zero, I will `continue` because there's no point in going any further with the number since the inverse will start with a leading 0.

Comment: @Jonathan FYI my computer just finished running up to 1 billion, the answer I got is **608720** numbers satisfy your criteria.

Comment: @Cyber: Our results agree up to a factor of 2. I think the difference might be due to whether you count `12, 21` and `21, 12` as one flipflop or two.

Comment: @unutbu Good catch, as written the above method considers that as two flips. I guess it's up to the OP.

Comment: @Cyber thanks again. Another question - where you say inverse = int(str(num)[::-1]) in the script, is that defining inverse? Can you explain that line to me please?

Comment: Sure, I convert the int to a str. Then I reverse the string using slicing (Google "python slicing syntax") basically I iterate over the during backwards. Once reversed, I convert it back to an int.

Answer (score 0):

```
def check_odds(num):
    for x in num:
        if x not in odds:
            return False
    return True 

for x in xrange(11,1000):
    if x%10 != 0:
        invert = int(str(x)[::-1])
        flip_sum = str(x + invert)
        if check_odds(flip_sum):
            print "Number: " +  str(x) + "   Reverse: " + str(invert) + "   flip_sum: " + flip_sum
```

output:

```
Number: 12   Reverse: 21   flip_sum: 33
Number: 14   Reverse: 41   flip_sum: 55
Number: 16   Reverse: 61   flip_sum: 77
Number: 18   Reverse: 81   flip_sum: 99
Number: 21   Reverse: 12   flip_sum: 33
Number: 23   Reverse: 32   flip_sum: 55
Number: 25   Reverse: 52   flip_sum: 77
Number: 27   Reverse: 72   flip_sum: 99
Number: 32   Reverse: 23   flip_sum: 55
Number: 34   Reverse: 43   flip_sum: 77
Number: 36   Reverse: 63   flip_sum: 99
Number: 41   Reverse: 14   flip_sum: 55
Number: 43   Reverse: 34   flip_sum: 77
Number: 45   Reverse: 54   flip_sum: 99
Number: 52   Reverse: 25   flip_sum: 77
Number: 54   Reverse: 45   flip_sum: 99
Number: 61   Reverse: 16   flip_sum: 77
Number: 63   Reverse: 36   flip_sum: 99 
Number: 72   Reverse: 27   flip_sum: 99
Number: 81   Reverse: 18   flip_sum: 99
Number: 209   Reverse: 902   flip_sum: 1111
Number: 219   Reverse: 912   flip_sum: 1131
Number: 229   Reverse: 922   flip_sum: 1151
Number: 239   Reverse: 932   flip_sum: 1171
................................
..........
```

if you want to count:

```
def check_odds(num):
    for x in num:
        if x not in odds:
            return False
    return True 
count = 0
for x in xrange(11,1000):
    if x%10 != 0:
        invert = int(str(x)[::-1])
        flip_sum = str(x + invert)
        if check_odds(flip_sum):
            count += 1
print count
```

Comment: When I try to use this up to 1 billion I get a memory error. Is there a way I can tell it to tell me how many results it's getting instead of printing them all?

Comment: yep just count it, its 100000000 ,it will take time to count toooo

Comment: @Jonathan you using python 2x ??

Comment: The problem is I can't run it. When I change the range to 1,000,000,000 it gives me a memory error.

I'm thinking instead of printing all of the data (number, inverse, etc.) have it count for each iteration

Something like:

if flip_sum%2 !=0:
   print (iteration of 1 to final number)

Comment: You need to check that all digits are odd, not just the last digit.  121 shouldn't be a valid sum.

Comment: @Jonathan now check it may help you